# VS Code can't find praw methods automatically

Tags: python, praw

I'm coding a bot for reddit but I'm having difficulties. VS Code can't find the praw methods. However, this situation is for some methods.

For example, when I use use

```
reddit.
```

It shows me all parameters Reddit instance have. However, when I use this:

```
reddit.subreddit("test").
```

It shows me nothing. How can I solve this problem? Or what am I doing wrong?